# Getting file extension in C language

Tags: c

Say there is a file called 12345.jpg. In C, how can I get the file extension so that I can compare with some file extension? If there are any inbuilt functions, kindly please let me know.

Comment: [SO 290488](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290488) covers a lot of the same ground.

Comment: So is this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949/how-to-get-file-extension-from-string-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting file extension in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309471/getting-file-extension-in-c)

Comment: [SO 51949](http://stackoverflow.com/q/51949/), mentioned by [Ofek Shilon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89706/ofek-shilon), is a C++ question.  The answers are not appropriate for C.  [SO 5309471](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5309471/), mentioned by [nibot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462335/nibot), was asked a year or so after this.  There's a cross-reference back to this question, though.  SO 290488, mentioned by YT, is tagged with both C++ and C, though the code it shows is pure C (that would also compile in C++, I think, based on eyeballing, not on testing it).

Answer (score 10):

A function to do that, along with a test harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *getExt (const char *fspec) {
    char *e = strrchr (fspec, '.');
    if (e == NULL)
        e = ""; // fast method, could also use &(fspec[strlen(fspec)]).
    return e;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf ("[%s] - > [%s]\n", argv[i], getExt (argv[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running this with:

```
./program abc abc. abc.1 .xyz abc.def abc.def.ghi
```

gives you:

```
[abc] - > []
[abc.] - > [.]
[abc.1] - > [.1]
[.xyz] - > [.xyz]
[abc.def] - > [.def]
[abc.def.ghi] - > [.ghi]
```

Comment: +1 for `strrchr`.  Best method for finding the last instance of a character in a string.

Comment: Just in case anyone misses it. `getExt()` assumes that `fspec` is a basename, not full path.  Consider for e.g., `my.dir/file`.  Use `basename()` to get the basename from a full path.

Answer (score 6):

Probably:

```
#include <string.h>

char *extn = strrchr(filename, '.');
```

That will give you a pointer to the period of the extension, or a null pointer if there is no extension.  You might need to do some more due diligence to ensure that there isn't a slash after the dot, amongst other things.

Comment: `strrchr(filename+1,'.');` would handle names like `.svn` that start with a dot but have no extension.

Comment: @drawnonward - indubitably, if you consider that to be a file name with no extension, rather than as an extension with no name.  That is another of the 'due diligence' cases to be considered.  However, if the OP is looking to compare the found extension with a fairly short list of known extensions, then the fact that `.svn` is not in the list means it probably won't matter anyway.

Comment: @drawnonward: I misread what you were saying - you make a valid point.  However, that wouldn't help with absolute pathnames which start with a '/', or relative names containing a slash (`subdir/.svn`).  There's a case for saying you need to find the start of the basename of the file (after the last slash, but you have to worry about trailing slashes and root) and then look for a dot not in the first position.  I guess that means the parent directory '..' has the name 'dot' followed by an extension starting with a dot and nothing more...There's usually another curve ball to deal with.

Comment: @drawnonward Might cause segmentation fault if filename is empty string.

Answer (score 2):

There's a portable CRT solution: [_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx).

In windows there's also an undocumented shell32 API called [PathGetExtension](http://binaryworld.net/Main/CodeDetail.aspx?CodeId=3825), but that's evil in so many ways that I probably shouldn't have noted that.

Comment: This is obviously some new definition of the word "portable" of which I was previously unaware :-) With apologies to Douglas Adams of HHGTTG fame.

Comment: Indeed, never seen the word "portable" and a link to msdn in the same sentence:-)

Comment: My bad, my bad!
Won't edit the answer, for others to enjoy  :)

Comment: Well, yeah, the answer is still useful so I wouldn't edit it. If you're on an MS platform, it's probably preferable to use `_splitpath` than write your own (such as in my answer).

Comment: Of course - I considered removing 'portable' (where was my head, really?) but dropped it.

Answer (score -1):

Use strchr
First array member will give you filename
Second array member will give you extension