# Getting file extension in C

Tags: c, string, file

How do you get a file extension (like `.tiff`) from a filename in C?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting file extension in C language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035225/getting-file-extension-in-c-language)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
const char *get_filename_ext(const char *filename) {
    const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if(!dot || dot == filename) return "";
    return dot + 1;
}

printf("%s\n", get_filename_ext("test.tiff"));
printf("%s\n", get_filename_ext("test.blah.tiff"));
printf("%s\n", get_filename_ext("test."));
printf("%s\n", get_filename_ext("test"));
printf("%s\n", get_filename_ext("..."));
```

Comment: After `dot = strrchr(filename, '.');`, `dot != NULL` implies that `*dot == '.'` so your test ought to be simply `if(dot)`.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `renamer.c:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strrchr’`

Comment: For most practical purposes, if the last dot is the first character of the basename, then it should not be treated as a file extenstion. For example in `~/.forward`, ".forward" isn't an extension.

Comment: That doesn't really matter... because I'm just using it batch rename my photos.

Comment: Once you have extracted the file extension a useful addendum might be the [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) routine from `string.h`. It will allow you to compare the file extension with a given string and perform a certain action, e.g. `if (strcmp(ext,"tiff") == 0) ...`

Answer (score 26):

Find the last dot with `strrchr`, then advance 1 char

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <string.h> /* strrchr */

ext = strrchr(filename, '.');
if (!ext) {
    /* no extension */
} else {
    printf("extension is %s\n", ext + 1);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to copy it - you'll return a part of the string which ends with the end of the original string, so no modifications are necessary.

Comment: Well if he doesn't copy it and tries to free the extension, it will throw an error. If he frees the filename then it will collectively free the extension but in general, it could lead to issues. Malloc doesn't care about the pointer you assign, it has a separate spot in memory where it keeps track of what is allocated and the size of said allocation. Even if you allocate 200 bytes and use 10 of them, malloc will still free 200. I'm unsure if there's something I'm missing that would make strdup(ext+1) a lesser option, if there is, please comment further.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `strrchr` function, which searches for the last occurrence of a character in a string, to find the final dot.  From there, you can read off the rest of the string as the extension.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version which works also for file (or directory) *paths*:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *FileSuffix(const char path[])
{
    const char *result;
    int i, n;

    assert(path != NULL);
    n = strlen(path);
    i = n - 1;
    while ((i > 0) && (path[i] != '.') && (path[i] != '/') && (path[i] != '\\')) {
        i--;
    }
    if ((i > 0) && (i < n - 1) && (path[i] == '.') && (path[i - 1] != '/') && (path[i - 1] != '\\')) {
        result = path + i;
    } else {
        result = path + n;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix(""), "") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("."), "") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("f"), "") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo"), "") == 0);     
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo."), "") == 0);    
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix(".foo"), "") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo.bar"), ".bar") == 0); 
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo/.bar"), "") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo\\.bar"), "") == 0);   
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo/bar.baz.qux"), ".qux") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo\\bar.baz.qux"), ".qux") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo.bar.baz/qux"), "") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(FileSuffix("foo.bar.baz\\qux"), "") == 0);    
    return 0;
}
```