# Read Tags for few MP3 files

Tags: c

This code work to read one mp3 file ID3V1 tags. But I have a directory with few MP3 files. I would like to add something that allow my program to read all MP3 files which are in the directory.
And then I have to export all ID3V1 tags into a CSV file.

I don't know how to do that, any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{

char tag[3];
char title[30];
char artist[30];
char album[30];
char year[4];
char comment[30];
unsigned char genre;

}mp3Info;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
if ( argc != 1 )
{
printf( "Please choose one file: %s <song.mp3> \n", argv[0] );
} type FILE,
file = fopen("song.mp3", "rb"); 

if (file == NULL) {

printf("I couldn't open: %s for reading.\n");
exit(0);
}

else
{
mp3Info tag_in;

fseek(file, -sizeof(mp3Info), SEEK_END);

if (fread(&tag_in, sizeof(mp3Info), 1, file) != 1)
{
printf("Could not read the tag\n");
exit (0);
}


if (memcmp(tag_in.tag, "TAG", 3) == 0)
{
printf("Title: %.30s\n", tag_in.title);
printf("Artist: %.30s\n", tag_in.artist);
printf("Album: %.30s\n", tag_in.album);
printf("Year: %.4s\n", tag_in.year);

if (tag_in.comment[28] == '\0')
{
printf("Comment: %.28s\n", tag_in.comment);
printf("Track: %d\n", tag_in.comment[29]);
}

else
{
printf("Comment: %.30s\n", tag_in.comment);
}
printf("Genre: %d\n", tag_in.genre);
}

else
{
fprintf(stderr, "The program has failed to get the Tags\n");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

fclose(file);
return 0;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep things short I'll just link relevant answers that you can then combine to solve your problem.

The first thing you should do is list all the files in the directory, as shown here [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Once you got that, you should loop through your files (which is also explained on the previous link), check which ones are MP3 files. A simple way to do this (although not the best one) is to check its extension, as shown here [Getting file extension in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309471/getting-file-extension-in-c?s=1%7C3.2997) For each MP3 file you find, simply use your code to parse it, and instead of using `printf` write everything to a CSV file.

As for the CSV file, the format is simple enough that you can simply use `fprintf` or `fwrite` to write everything. If you are planning to read the data with Microsoft Excel do not forget to put `sep=,` at the top of the file or it won't read it correctly, it already happened to me once (it will work fine on LibreOffice without it)

Comment: That's work but I have a problem when I do : fprintf("this is an example")
My variable "this is an example" is divided into 4 cases because of the spaces, how can I fix it?

Comment: Mhh no, that should not happen, as specified in the [RFC4180's document](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) in point 4 page 2 `Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored.`. It also states that you cannot have a comma at the end of the line. So that means if you run the following code : `fprintf(file, "field1,field2 with spaces, field3\n");` it should work fine. Do not forget the line break at the end.

Comment: Also as said in my answer, if you use Excel, don't forget to add `sep=,` on the first line, that means my complete example would look this way `fprintf(file, "sep=,\nfield1,field2 with spaces, field3\n");`.