# Get FILE extension from a file or path

Tags: c, string, file, file-extension

I'm trying to create a method that can get the extension of a file.
I found multiple alternatives and this one was my solution:

```
const char *getExt(const char *filename) {
    const char *ext = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if(!ext || ext == filename){
        return "No Extension";
    }else{
        return ext + 1;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is with the extension `.tar.gz`.

How can I select this kind of extension too without messing every other extension with only one dot (`.`)?

Comment: Select? Messing? Please clarify.

Comment: file extensions are only a *convention* (at least on Linux). You could have several ones.

Comment: Find the *first* `'.'` instead of the last? Since "extension" is just a convention, even on Windows these days, there are no real rules that specify what it is. If you had e.g. `file.name.with.many.dots`, what would the "extension" be?

Comment: Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309471/getting-file-extension-in-c

Comment: You need to make a definition.  What is the "file extension" of a file named "my.great.photo.jpg"?

Comment: Isn't .tar.gz 's extension gz?

Answer (score 0):

In use by me for many years:

```
char *GetExtension (const char *str)                // Extract the extension from the string  (incl '.')
{
    const char *pstr;
    if (!str ||!*str) return((char *)str);

    pstr = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while ((*pstr != '/') && (*pstr != '\\') && (*pstr != '.') && (pstr > str))
            pstr--;
    if (*pstr != '.') return (0);
    return ((char *)pstr); //includes separator
}
```